# Issue Symfony and AngularJS variable

Tags: angularjs, symfony, syntax

I am new with Symfony and Angular and today i worked a lot to find a solution to my problem but with no result ...

In symfony i get a parameter witch is :

```
{{app.request.baseUrl}}
```

Then in a form i use AngularJs :

```
<form role="form" action="[[ {{app.request.baseUrl}} + '/stats/' + inputSummoner + '/' + inputRegion]]" method="post">
...
</form>
```

And here is the problem i can't read a Symfony variable in AngularJS command...

```
this value {{app.request.baseUrl}} is empty when i use it in the AngularJS quotes
```

So i tried another solution but with no result :

In my html.twig i put an hidden value with an id :

```
<input type="hidden" id="baseUrl" value="{{app.request.baseUrl}}"/>
```

And in my AngularJS controller i try to update the value :

```
var timer=false;
$scope.baseUrl='';
$scope.$watch('baseUrl', function() {
   $scope.baseUrl=document.getElementById("uriBase");
});
```

That doesn't work so if someone have a solution it could be helpful ^^

For the moment i use the javascript command :

```
window.location.href
```

don't know if it's good or not but it works ..

Thanks a lot !

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Comment: why do you use [[ and ]] with {{app.request.baseUrl}} ?

Comment: You do it wrong. 
It's relly bad pratice to mix rendering view. 
Angular application should do this, not syfmony. You have to use symfony only like API backend

Comment: Yes the brackets [[]] are interpolation :) ...Well but how can i do this with angular? is this correct to replace the {{app.request.baseUrl}} by the javascript window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach wont work, because `{{app.request.baseUrl}}` only works when the template is rendered in Twig.

Your second approach has a few bugs, controller should look like this:

```
var timer=false;
$scope.baseUrl=document.getElementById("baseUrl").value;
```

But you should stick with the third approach. AngularJS has a `$location` service based on `window.location` for your convenience: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 0):

The correct action should look like:

```
<form role="form" action="[[ '{{app.request.baseUrl}}' + '/stats/' + inputSummoner + '/' + inputRegion]]" method="post">
```